# sqlexception cannot insert duplicate key row

Tags: c#, sql

Tried to alter my SQL statement to change the format of how user names are create. I am creating dummy data for testing on a webpage so I just need multiple users. I want to change the name for the user currently it is `student{integer}@email.com` and I wanted to change name to `student{integer}`

**Error**

> **SqlException**: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index 'UX_Users'. The duplicate key value is (1, student0@email.com).
>   The statement has been terminated.

**SQL statement**

```
string basestring = "student{0}@email.com";
string userName = "Student{0}";

using (Database dc = new Database())
{
    dc.Connection.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    {
        string email = string.Format(basestring,i);
        string sName = string.Format(userName, i);
        User u = new User(){ Name = sName, UserName = email, InstitutionUniqueID = email, Email = email, CreationDate=DateTime.Now, InstitutionsID=1, GUID= Guid.NewGuid() };
        dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u); 
    }
    dc.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
}
```

This is where I am getting the error:

```
dc.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
```

I am using linqpad to test this out.

Comment: How is `'UX_Users'` index defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
string basestring = "student{0}@email.com";
string userName = "Student{0}";

using (Database dc = new Database())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    {
         dc.Connection.Open();
        string email = string.Format(basestring,i);
        string sName = string.Format(userName, i);
        User u = new User(){ Name = sName, UserName = email, InstitutionUniqueID = email, Email = email, CreationDate=DateTime.Now, InstitutionsID=1, GUID= Guid.NewGuid() };
        dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u); 
        dc.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
        dc.Connection.Close();
    }

}
```

you just need to place your submit changes inside your loop

Best Regards

Comment: i am still getting the same error. I ran this statement and then after running i added the `string sName....` and then tried to run again. Do i need to drop the table and run it?

Comment: yup maybe the records already exist on your table. Are you using SQL Server ?

Comment: i could use it - i was testing this piece in linqpad but i could do this in SQL Server management

Comment: just delete all the records from the table drop/create .